# Non-persistence of class variables in StateMachine in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I am writing an App which declares some class variables in StateMachine as for example:

```
    Label Logo=null;        Image helpIcon=null;
```

and these are initialised in initVars()

```
    Logo = new Label(resFile.getImage("ic_action_play.png"));
    helpIcon = resFile.getImage("ic_action_help.png");
```

beforeMain() calls createMenu() to setup a menu dynamically.

```
    private void createMenu(int menuNumber, Form targetForm) {
    Toolbar tb = targetForm.getToolbar();

    if (menuNumber == MAIN_MENU && !menuInitialised) {
        tb.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, Logo);
        menuInitialised = true;
    }

    tb.addCommandToRightBar("", helpIcon, (e)->getDialog(1));
    etc...
```

This works fine.
One of the menu items shows a Dialog, "Setup" and if I set a breakpoint in beforeSetup(Form f)
all the class variables have been reset to null. The instance of StateMachine hasn't changed
and the Ctor is not called. The only way I could retain the initialisations was to make the (class) variables that are 
initialised in initVars() static. Is that right or am I not doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

initVars happens before class init code e.g.:

```
private int myValue = 1;

protected void initVars() {
  myValue = 2;

  // will print 2
  System.out.println(myValue);
}

public Statemachine() {
  // will print 1
  System.out.println(myValue);
}
```

The output of this will be:

```
2
1
```

As initVars happens before the constructor and initializing a value in the class scope is the equivalent of setting it in the constructor. The solution is not to initialize the variable and only set it in the `initVars()`.

This is one of the old GUI builder oddities which is why we are moving towards the [new GUI builder](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html).